# Installation of Paraview 5 on Ubuntu 16.04: can't open Paraview due to libGL errors

Tags: drivers, software-installation, parallels

I hope it's OK to cross-post; I have asked this question on StackExchange too.

I'm trying to install the latest version of Paraview (version 5.1; http://www.paraview.org) on Ubuntu 16.04. After downloading, when I try to open Paraview, I get these errors:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I have searched extensively on Google, but get very few results related to this error. Most are related to using software that isn't Paraview. I'm a bit of a newbie as far as Ubuntu and would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

This probably isn't relevant, but just in case, I'm a Mac user accessing Ubuntu via Parallels.

Comment: You are using an obsolete version of Ubuntu. Update to a currently supported version and you will be able to do `sudo apt-get install paraview`

Comment: Zanna, thank you very much.  I had no idea.  I'll give it a go.  Unfortunately, this may be a problem because I'm running software that may only work with my current version.

Comment: Even so, it's not safe to use an unsupported version. If you have that problem, you must find alternatives :)

Comment: Zanna, I did the update and am now running Ubuntu 16.04.  However, I'm still getting the same errors when trying to access Paraview 5.

Comment: good work :) did you try to install from repository (`sudo apt install paraview`) or from the website download?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Zanna.  I Installed from the website (http://www.paraview.org/download/).  Also (not sure if this matters), I used the download that I already had from yesterday when I was running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Please install the repository version by doing `sudo apt install paraview` in a terminal - this will allow the package management system to handle the dependencies for you

Comment: If you get 'not found' do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install paraview` sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: I think it did work...  Now I just have to find where it was installed!

Comment: Zanna, I'm embarrassed to say that I can't figure out where it is installed, but it is installed!  I typed "paraview" and the version is 5.0.1.  Thank you very much for all your help and fast responses.  I'd love to give you credit for this question, but I think you'd need to post an answer.  Would you have time to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraview is available in the repositories of all currently supported Ubuntu versions, so regardless of which one you are running, you can install it by opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install paraview
```

Then you can launch from a terminal by typing `paraview` or by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `paraview` or by searching in the dash.

It's always preferable to install any application from repositories, because then dependencies and updates will be handled by our lovely package management system. You should only download an app from a website as a last resort if you can't install it the secure and easy way :)